# Lights brain teaser

Tags: puzzle

$N$ lights are off. There are $N$ switches. Switch $i$ controls light $i$, and it may control other lights in addition to light $i$. The switches and lights are interlocked (if switch $i$ can turn on light $j$, switch $j$ can also turn on light $i$). Proves that there must be a way to turn on all lights.

I tried to express the lights and switches relationship into a matrix. For sure, it is symmetric, and I cannot move on. I tried induction, but I've got no idea. Any ideas?

Comment: So when you say "switch $i$ controls light $i$", you mean that when you flip switch $i$, the state of light $i$ changes? So light $i$ is on if an odd number of the switches that "control" it are on?

Comment: @joriki That is how I would read it

Comment: Remark: it's definitely not true that any light state can be reached (imagine for example if every switch toggled every light). So we can't hope to show that the matrix is invertible or anything like that; this has to be a special property of the all-lights-on state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first saw this solution in [*Algebraic Combinatorics: Walks, Trees, Tableaux, and More*](https://klein.mit.edu/%7Erstan/algcomb/) by  Richard Stanley, page 238. He says that a special case of this problem, where the switches are on an $m\times n$ grid and each switch is connected to its orthogonal neighbors, was open for "many years". This seems to suggest this problem is pretty hard, but perhaps knowing that the correct approach is linear algebra for general graphs makes it considerably easier. I give a pretty thorough outline below, with some gaps for you to fill in.

---

Consider the adjacency matrix $A$, where $A_{i,j}=1$ if the switch for light $i$ also controls light $j$, and $0$ otherwise. This means $A$ is symmetric with ones on the diagonal. We view the entries of $A$ as elements of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Let $\bf 1$ be the all-ones column vector. In order to prove you can turn on all the lights, you need to show that $\bf 1$ is in the image of $A$. To do this, we use this fact from linear algebra:

> $\text{im }A=(\text{ker }A^\top)^\perp$.

This means that in order to show ${\bf 1}\in \text{im }A$, it suffices to show that $\bf 1$ is orthogonal to every vector in the null space of $A^\top$, which is just $A$.

To this end, let $z$ be any vector in $\text{ker A}$, so $Az=0$. We need to show $z^\top{\bf 1}=0$. If you write $A=I+B$, with $I$ the identity matrix and $B$ a symmetric matrix with zeroes on the diagonal, then
$$
0=z^\top Az=z^\top Iz+z^\top Bz
$$
Now, you can then show that

- $z^\top Bz=0$, and
- $z^\top Iz=z^\top {\bf 1}$,

so the above implies $z$ is orthogonal to $\bf 1$, which is what we wanted. I leave proving the last two bullets as an exercise to the reader.

---

$\text{im }A=(\text{ker }A^\top)^\perp$ is usually stated in the context of inner product spaces over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, but it works just as well for $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$-matrices, where the "inner product" is defined to be $\langle v,w\rangle= v^\top w$ for column vectors $v,w$. Here is the proof, behind a spoiler in case you want to try to figure it out yourself.

> $\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}\newcommand{\ker}{\operatorname{ker}}$ First, we show $\im A\subseteq (\ker A^\top)^\perp$. Let $y\in \im A$, so that $y=Ax$ for some $x$, and let $z\in \ker A^\top$, so that $A^\top z=0$. Then $$z^\top y=z^\top (Ax)=(A^\top z)^\top y=0y=0,$$ proving $y$ is orthogonal to every vector in $\ker A^\top$, so $\im A\subseteq (\ker A^\top)^\perp$. You then prove equality by counting dimensions, since $$\dim(\im A)=n-\dim (\ker A^T)=n-(n-\dim((\ker A^\top)^\perp))=\dim((\ker A^\top)^\perp).$$The first equation is the rank-nullity theorem, and the second is $\dim V=n-\dim V^\perp$, applied to $V=\ker A^\top$. The equation $\dim V=n-\dim V^\perp$ follows by applying the rank-nullity theorem to a matrix whose rows form a basis for $V$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed solution!